# Displaying Logged In User Specific data from MYSQL using JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, session, jstl

I have run into a problem where I have to display certain data that is present in the Ratings table of MYSQL depending upon the user that is logged in.

The heirarchy is  as below :

login.jsp --> check.jsp --> welcome.jsp

I have to display data on Welcome.jsp depending on the user who is  logged in. I am unable to get the user parameter to server as an input for the sql query that displays the user specific data. Here are my files.

login.jsp

```
<%-- 
Document   : login
Created on : May 15, 2012, 10:36:24 AM
Author     : Diaa
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function validate(){
var username=document.form.user.value;
var password=document.form.pass.value;
if(username==""){
alert("Enter Username!");
return false;
}
if(password==""){
alert("Enter Password!");
return false;
}
return true;
 }
</script>

    <div align="center">
   <div class='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.jsp'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='login.jsp'><span>Login</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='index.jsp'><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="check.jsp" onsubmit="javascript:return  validate();">

<div align="center">
<h1>USER LOGIN</h1>
<table>
<tr><td bgcolor="#FF9900">Username:</td><td bgcolor="#33CCCC"><input type="text"  name="user"></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#FF9900">Password:</td><td bgcolor="#33CCCC"><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

check.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
String user=request.getParameter("user");
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

 Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recommend","root","root");  
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select UserID,password from Users where   UserID='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
      int count=0;
      while(rs.next())
      {

               count++;
      }

                if(count>0)
      {
        out.println("welcome "+user);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp?msg=welcome "+user +"   <a   href=\"index.jsp\">logout</a>");
        session.removeAttribute("user");
      }
      else
      {
                   response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?msg=Invalid Username or Password");
      }
      %>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

   <%-- Database Interaction Queries Start --%>
   <% String user=(String)session.getAttribute(user); %>
   <sql:setDataSource var="genretype" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/recommend"
   user="root"  password="root"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${genretype}" var="result">
SELECT * from Genres;
</sql:query>

<sql:query dataSource="${genretype}" var="result1">
SELECT * from Ratings where UserID = ?
<sql:param value="${user}"/>
</sql:query>

 <%-- Database Interaction Queries End --%>    



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Heading</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <div class='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.jsp'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='login.jsp'><span>Login</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='index.jsp'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>    
    <%String msg=request.getParameter("msg");
    if(msg!=null){
    %>

<label><font color="red"><%=msg%></font></label> 
<% 
}
 %>
    <h1>Sample Title</h1>
    <%--For Displaying Genre List Start --%>
    <div>
    <div align="left" position:absolute left:1200px>

             <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
   <ul id="tab_nav">


   <li><c:out value="${row.GenreName}"/></li>

   </ul>

   </c:forEach>    

        </div>


    <div id="box" >

    <table border="1">
             <c:forEach var="row" items="${result1.rows}">

    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${row.Rating}"/></td>              
        <td><c:out value="${row.UserID}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.GenreName}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${row.MovieName}"/></td>
    </tr>

  </c:forEach>    
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Can anyone please look into this and let me know what I am missing here :( Please feel free to ask back any other information apart from the code posted.

Fingers Crossed.. Awaiting for help!!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append HTML to the URL parameter of your `sendRedirect()` method call. There could be encoding issues with it and so it may be failing:

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp?msg=welcome "+user +"   <a   href=\"index.jsp\">logout</a>");
```

This should simply be

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp?user=" + user);
```

with the message being constructed in the JSP as

```
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
    <label><font color="red">Welcome ${user}</font></label><br />
    <a href="logout.jsp">logout</a>
</c:if>
```

If this doesn't solve the issue please update your question with how's the application behaving. Do you see any errors? Are you logging the exceptions anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I did a sample code here for you to check out.
 Here is a sample login.jsp form:

```
<form action="check.jsp" method="post"> 
           <table border="0">
        <tr>       
       <input type="text" name="user" id="user"/>
           </tr>
    <tr>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
    </tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>

</td>

       </table>

       </form>
```

Then,the check.jsp could look this way:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

        <%
            Connection con;
            ResultSet rs;
            PreparedStatement ps;
            String query;

            String user = request.getParameter("user");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recommend","root","root");
                query = "select userID,password from Users where userID='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'";
                ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                //ps.setString(1,request.getParameter("user"));
                //ps.setString(1,request.getParameter("pass"));
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){

                session.setAttribute("user", user);
          %>
          <jsp:forward page="welcome.jsp"/>     
       <%   
            }else{

               response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

            }    

            }catch(Exception e){
              out.println(e);
            }

        %>
```

from the code above,you can see that after the querying of the database the attribute of the user is set and also the check.jsp forward that to the welcome.jsp page with that attribute of the user that has been set,else if the user or password is Incorrect,the person is being redirected to the login.jsp page.

The welcome.jsp page looks this way:

```
<body>
        <% String user = (String)session.getAttribute("user");%>
        <% if(user == null){
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}else{
        out.println("Welcome "+user);
        }
        %>
    </body>
```

In the welcome.jsp page,it retrieves the session attribute of the user that is logged in via the session.getAttribute() method.It then checks if the session attribute is null and then redirects back to the user,else it prints Welcome + the user.Note that the user being printed is from the session.getAttribute which is gotten from the session.setAttribute in the check.jsp,that way you are able to get the user parameter as input from the login. I hope this helps.